# The specified source 'MySource' is invalid

Tags: nuget

I am trying to push packages to the VSTS package manager from the command line like this

```
nuget.exe push -Source "MySource" -ApiKey VSTS *.nupkg
```

But I am getting the following error

```
The specified source 'MySource' is invalid. Please provide a valid source.
```

Event though the source exists.

Any idea why it doesn´t recognize MySource?

I am using TFS2018.

This used to work initially and I pushed multiple packages. I also tried removing the source and creating a new one but the problem persists. Any help suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Two cents: I wasn't putting my packageSourceName in double quotes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I forgot to add the source using the following command:

```
nuget.exe sources Add -Name "MySource" -Source <url>
```

Comment: This worked for me too while assisting someone else. Whats odd is we had VS already setup with the correct source, but nuget.exe wasn't seeing it. We added the source via this command, and then things worked. We checked the sources in VS again and either the Add replaced the existing one, or its storing sources somewhere else and it's not the same as the sources in VS.

Answer (score 13):

In my case it was not letting me use the feed because of having it disabled in the VS 2019.
Just go to the **VisualStudio** and from the **Tools** menu select **Nuget Package Manager** and then **Package Manager settings**

[image]

and then from the opened Dialog, select **Package Sources** and in the list of sources, check the one that you want to enable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the samme issue but in my case the problem is that I have the target source disable on my source list (I disable it but I forgot to re enable it)

Comment: It would be great if you share the command to check the target source status here

Answer (score 1):

I found the different documentation confusing.  Some places, I saw that `--source` should be set to `domain_name/repository_name`, however it worked for me once I used the name from "Avaiable Package Sources -> Name".  I.e. `--source "My Package source"` from the above example.